# Deployment of Tika-tesseract docker on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, tesseract, apache-tika

This works on localhost, but not on Heroku.

Here is my dockerfile -

```
FROM java:7
MAINTAINER Matt Fullerton <matt.fullerton@gmail.com>

RUN mkdir /setup
ADD install.sh /setup/install.sh
RUN /setup/install.sh
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /srv/tika-server-1.*-SNAPSHOT.jar --host=0.0.0.0 --port=$PORT

EXPOSE 9998
```

Repo is https://github.com/mattfullerton/tika-tesseract-docker

Steps I followed from cli-

```
$ heroku login
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-container-registry
$ heroku container:login -v
$ heroku container:push web --app tika-server
$ heroku container:release web --app tika-server
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Specify the steps you have tried to make it work on Heroku. Do you have a heroku.yml file?

Comment: @TinNguyen I have updated my question with steps, there is no .yml . We are just trying to run container on Heroku.

Comment: heroku.yml is required see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Comment: I added a heroku.yml in root wit this - 
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile